# Struggling to open PDF file in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, pdf, acrobat

Im struggling to open a pdf file in Internet explorer

Console shows up a warning

```
"HTML1527: DOCTYPE expected. The shortest valid doctype is "<!DOCTYPE html>"."
```

Markup rendered

```
<head></head>
<body topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" scroll="no"> 
    <embed width="100%" height="100%" src="websitename/file.pdf" type="application/pdf" fullscreen="yes">
</body>
```

I've also tried disabling "Display PDF in browser" option from Adobe Reader Preferences, still no luck.

Comment: Your HTML is incomplete. You should have DOCTYPE, meta & title tag in `<head>` and `<html>` start & end tags.

Comment: Hi Shivan, Sorry the URL im trying to go to is a pdf file, http://websitename.com/pdfile.pdf and strangely IE is trying to render it as an html file with an embed

Comment: Which IE version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

To allow Internet Explorer to open PDF directly, ensure Acrobat Viewer add-on is enabled.

Reference: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie9-windows_7/how-to-force-internet-explorer-9-to-open-pdf-in/76e03210-d03a-4c13-bcd9-ac899c3a0ae1?msgId=e7c98b6a-de1b-4873-9210-4ba0a0c574ae

Comment: Hi mate, still no luck, disabled all addons

Comment: You have to **ENABLE** it .

Comment: oh crap, sorry -i'll blame it on alcohol. Enabled all addons still not working, I think this is the issue with my computer as i can see those pdfs loading on IE in browsertack, i'll dig it up. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should see if other web-based PDFs open correctly in your browser. Assuming they do this will confirm a problem in the way the content is being sent from the server.

You can detect exactly what the problem is using a tool like IEWatch to see the headers and data. I would suspect that the content-disposition is incorrect.

There are common causes of this type of issue detailed here:

http://www.websupergoo.com/support.htm?nav=6.16

I work on the ABCpdf .NET software component hence the link above. It's just what I know. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this error in a similar context and it was caused by my server using SSL, and the pdf source server not, causing a type of mixed-content problem with IE.

I used a proxy page to pull the pdf via https and that worked. Only remaining issue is the PDF file name got lost to adobe reader, so when the user goes to save, it prompts them for 'proxy.pdf'